# How can I install VMware Workstation 8 on Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, 64-bit, vmware

I installed VMware Workstation 8 on Ubuntu 14.04, but when I run it, it fails to compile/build the modules with an error saying "Unable to start services."

Here is the modconfig log:

```
2014-11-10T10:57:16.143-08:00| vthread-3| I120: Log for VMware Workstation pid=5268 version=8.0.6 build=build-1035888 option=Release
2014-11-10T10:57:16.143-08:00| vthread-3| I120: The process is 64-bit.
2014-11-10T10:57:16.143-08:00| vthread-3| I120: Host codepage=UTF-8 encoding=UTF-8
2014-11-10T10:57:16.143-08:00| vthread-3| I120: Host is Linux 3.13.0-39-generic Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS
2014-11-10T10:57:16.143-08:00| vthread-3| I120: Msg_Reset:
2014-11-10T10:57:16.143-08:00| vthread-3| I120: [msg.dictionary.load.openFailed] Cannot open file "/usr/lib/vmware/settings": No such file or directory.
2014-11-10T10:57:16.143-08:00| vthread-3| I120: ----------------------------------------
2014-11-10T10:57:16.143-08:00| vthread-3| I120: PREF Optional preferences file not found at /usr/lib/vmware/settings. Using default values.
2014-11-10T10:57:16.143-08:00| vthread-3| I120: Msg_Reset:
2014-11-10T10:57:16.143-08:00| vthread-3| I120: [msg.dictionary.load.openFailed] Cannot open file "/root/.vmware/config": No such file or directory.
2014-11-10T10:57:16.143-08:00| vthread-3| I120: ----------------------------------------
2014-11-10T10:57:16.143-08:00| vthread-3| I120: PREF Optional preferences file not found at /root/.vmware/config. Using default values.
2014-11-10T10:57:16.143-08:00| vthread-3| I120: Msg_Reset:
2014-11-10T10:57:16.143-08:00| vthread-3| I120: [msg.dictionary.load.openFailed] Cannot open file "/root/.vmware/preferences": No such file or directory.
2014-11-10T10:57:16.143-08:00| vthread-3| I120: ----------------------------------------
2014-11-10T10:57:16.143-08:00| vthread-3| I120: PREF Failed to load user preferences.
2014-11-10T10:57:16.143-08:00| vthread-3| W110: Logging to /tmp/vmware-root/modconfig-5268.log
2014-11-10T10:57:16.262-08:00| vthread-3| I120: modconf query interface initialized
2014-11-10T10:57:16.262-08:00| vthread-3| I120: modconf library initialized
2014-11-10T10:57:16.306-08:00| vthread-3| I120: Your GCC version: 4.8
2014-11-10T10:57:16.310-08:00| vthread-3| I120: Validating path /lib/modules/preferred/build/include for kernel release 3.13.0-39-generic
2014-11-10T10:57:16.310-08:00| vthread-3| I120: Failed to find /lib/modules/preferred/build/include/linux/version.h
2014-11-10T10:57:16.310-08:00| vthread-3| I120: Failed version test: /lib/modules/preferred/build/include/linux/version.h not found.
2014-11-10T10:57:16.310-08:00| vthread-3| I120: Validating path /lib/modules/3.13.0-39-generic/build/include for kernel release 3.13.0-39-generic
2014-11-10T10:57:16.312-08:00| vthread-3| I120: Your GCC version: 4.8
2014-11-10T10:57:16.323-08:00| vthread-3| I120: Your GCC version: 4.8
2014-11-10T10:57:16.337-08:00| vthread-3| I120: Header path /lib/modules/3.13.0-39-generic/build/include for kernel release 3.13.0-39-generic is valid.
2014-11-10T10:57:16.337-08:00| vthread-3| I120: Validating path /lib/modules/3.13.0-39-generic/build/include for kernel release 3.13.0-39-generic
2014-11-10T10:57:16.339-08:00| vthread-3| I120: Your GCC version: 4.8
2014-11-10T10:57:16.349-08:00| vthread-3| I120: Your GCC version: 4.8
2014-11-10T10:57:16.363-08:00| vthread-3| I120: Header path /lib/modules/3.13.0-39-generic/build/include for kernel release 3.13.0-39-generic is valid.
2014-11-10T10:57:16.382-08:00| vthread-3| I120: Trying to find a suitable PBM set for kernel 3.13.0-39-generic.
2014-11-10T10:57:16.385-08:00| vthread-3| I120: Trying to find a suitable PBM set for kernel 3.13.0-39-generic.
2014-11-10T10:57:16.387-08:00| vthread-3| I120: Trying to find a suitable PBM set for kernel 3.13.0-39-generic.
2014-11-10T10:57:16.389-08:00| vthread-3| I120: Trying to find a suitable PBM set for kernel 3.13.0-39-generic.
2014-11-10T10:57:16.390-08:00| vthread-3| I120: Trying to find a suitable PBM set for kernel 3.13.0-39-generic.
2014-11-10T10:57:16.408-08:00| vthread-3| I120: Trying to find a suitable PBM set for kernel 3.13.0-39-generic.
2014-11-10T10:57:16.410-08:00| vthread-3| I120: Trying to find a suitable PBM set for kernel 3.13.0-39-generic.
2014-11-10T10:57:16.412-08:00| vthread-3| I120: Trying to find a suitable PBM set for kernel 3.13.0-39-generic.
2014-11-10T10:57:16.415-08:00| vthread-3| I120: Trying to find a suitable PBM set for kernel 3.13.0-39-generic.
2014-11-10T10:57:16.418-08:00| vthread-3| I120: Trying to find a suitable PBM set for kernel 3.13.0-39-generic.
2014-11-10T10:57:16.421-08:00| vthread-3| I120: Validating path /lib/modules/preferred/build/include for kernel release 3.13.0-39-generic
2014-11-10T10:57:16.421-08:00| vthread-3| I120: Failed to find /lib/modules/preferred/build/include/linux/version.h
2014-11-10T10:57:16.421-08:00| vthread-3| I120: Failed version test: /lib/modules/preferred/build/include/linux/version.h not found.
2014-11-10T10:57:16.421-08:00| vthread-3| I120: Validating path /lib/modules/3.13.0-39-generic/build/include for kernel release 3.13.0-39-generic
2014-11-10T10:57:16.423-08:00| vthread-3| I120: Your GCC version: 4.8
2014-11-10T10:57:16.433-08:00| vthread-3| I120: Your GCC version: 4.8
2014-11-10T10:57:16.446-08:00| vthread-3| I120: Header path /lib/modules/3.13.0-39-generic/build/include for kernel release 3.13.0-39-generic is valid.
2014-11-10T10:57:16.465-08:00| vthread-3| I120: Trying to find a suitable PBM set for kernel 3.13.0-39-generic.
2014-11-10T10:57:16.467-08:00| vthread-3| I120: Trying to find a suitable PBM set for kernel 3.13.0-39-generic.
2014-11-10T10:57:16.470-08:00| vthread-3| I120: Trying to find a suitable PBM set for kernel 3.13.0-39-generic.
2014-11-10T10:57:16.473-08:00| vthread-3| I120: Trying to find a suitable PBM set for kernel 3.13.0-39-generic.
2014-11-10T10:57:16.475-08:00| vthread-3| I120: Trying to find a suitable PBM set for kernel 3.13.0-39-generic.
2014-11-10T10:57:16.478-08:00| vthread-3| I120: Validating path /lib/modules/preferred/build/include for kernel release 3.13.0-39-generic
2014-11-10T10:57:16.478-08:00| vthread-3| I120: Failed to find /lib/modules/preferred/build/include/linux/version.h
2014-11-10T10:57:16.478-08:00| vthread-3| I120: Failed version test: /lib/modules/preferred/build/include/linux/version.h not found.
2014-11-10T10:57:16.478-08:00| vthread-3| I120: Validating path /lib/modules/3.13.0-39-generic/build/include for kernel release 3.13.0-39-generic
2014-11-10T10:57:16.480-08:00| vthread-3| I120: Your GCC version: 4.8
2014-11-10T10:57:16.489-08:00| vthread-3| I120: Your GCC version: 4.8
2014-11-10T10:57:16.502-08:00| vthread-3| I120: Header path /lib/modules/3.13.0-39-generic/build/include for kernel release 3.13.0-39-generic is valid.
2014-11-10T10:57:16.535-08:00| vthread-3| I120: Trying to find a suitable PBM set for kernel 3.13.0-39-generic.
2014-11-10T10:57:16.537-08:00| vthread-3| I120: Trying to find a suitable PBM set for kernel 3.13.0-39-generic.
2014-11-10T10:57:16.539-08:00| vthread-3| I120: Trying to find a suitable PBM set for kernel 3.13.0-39-generic.
2014-11-10T10:57:16.542-08:00| vthread-3| I120: Trying to find a suitable PBM set for kernel 3.13.0-39-generic.
2014-11-10T10:57:16.545-08:00| vthread-3| I120: Trying to find a suitable PBM set for kernel 3.13.0-39-generic.
2014-11-10T10:57:16.905-08:00| vthread-3| I120: Trying to find a suitable PBM set for kernel 3.13.0-39-generic.
2014-11-10T10:57:16.905-08:00| vthread-3| I120: Validating path /lib/modules/3.13.0-39-generic/build/include for kernel release 3.13.0-39-generic
2014-11-10T10:57:16.908-08:00| vthread-3| I120: Your GCC version: 4.8
2014-11-10T10:57:16.918-08:00| vthread-3| I120: Your GCC version: 4.8
2014-11-10T10:57:16.931-08:00| vthread-3| I120: Header path /lib/modules/3.13.0-39-generic/build/include for kernel release 3.13.0-39-generic is valid.
2014-11-10T10:57:16.931-08:00| vthread-3| I120: Building module vmmon.
2014-11-10T10:57:16.932-08:00| vthread-3| I120: Extracting the sources of the vmmon module.
2014-11-10T10:57:16.977-08:00| vthread-3| I120: Building module with command: /usr/bin/make -j -C /tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmmon-only auto-build SUPPORT_SMP=1 HEADER_DIR=/lib/modules/3.13.0-39-generic/build/include CC=/usr/bin/gcc GREP=/usr/bin/make IS_GCC_3=no VMCCVER=4.8
2014-11-10T10:58:51.945-08:00| vthread-3| I120: Installing module vmmon from /tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmmon.o to /lib/modules/3.13.0-39-generic/misc.
2014-11-10T10:58:51.964-08:00| vthread-3| I120: Registering file: /usr/lib/vmware-installer/2.0/vmware-installer --register-file vmware-vmx regular /lib/modules/3.13.0-39-generic/misc/vmmon.ko
2014-11-10T10:59:03.867-08:00| vthread-3| I120: Trying to find a suitable PBM set for kernel 3.13.0-39-generic.
2014-11-10T10:59:03.867-08:00| vthread-3| I120: Validating path /lib/modules/3.13.0-39-generic/build/include for kernel release 3.13.0-39-generic
2014-11-10T10:59:03.870-08:00| vthread-3| I120: Your GCC version: 4.8
2014-11-10T10:59:03.880-08:00| vthread-3| I120: Your GCC version: 4.8
2014-11-10T10:59:03.892-08:00| vthread-3| I120: Header path /lib/modules/3.13.0-39-generic/build/include for kernel release 3.13.0-39-generic is valid.
2014-11-10T10:59:03.892-08:00| vthread-3| I120: Building module vmnet.
2014-11-10T10:59:03.892-08:00| vthread-3| I120: Extracting the sources of the vmnet module.
2014-11-10T10:59:03.933-08:00| vthread-3| I120: Building module with command: /usr/bin/make -j -C /tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmnet-only auto-build SUPPORT_SMP=1 HEADER_DIR=/lib/modules/3.13.0-39-generic/build/include CC=/usr/bin/gcc GREP=/usr/bin/make IS_GCC_3=no VMCCVER=4.8
2014-11-10T10:59:24.963-08:00| vthread-3| I120: Failed to compile module vmnet!
2014-11-10T10:59:24.968-08:00| vthread-3| I120: Trying to find a suitable PBM set for kernel 3.13.0-39-generic.
2014-11-10T10:59:24.968-08:00| vthread-3| I120: Validating path /lib/modules/3.13.0-39-generic/build/include for kernel release 3.13.0-39-generic
2014-11-10T10:59:24.971-08:00| vthread-3| I120: Your GCC version: 4.8
2014-11-10T10:59:24.981-08:00| vthread-3| I120: Your GCC version: 4.8
2014-11-10T10:59:24.993-08:00| vthread-3| I120: Header path /lib/modules/3.13.0-39-generic/build/include for kernel release 3.13.0-39-generic is valid.
2014-11-10T10:59:24.994-08:00| vthread-3| I120: Building module vmblock.
2014-11-10T10:59:24.994-08:00| vthread-3| I120: Extracting the sources of the vmblock module.
2014-11-10T10:59:25.019-08:00| vthread-3| I120: Building module with command: /usr/bin/make -j -C /tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmblock-only auto-build SUPPORT_SMP=1 HEADER_DIR=/lib/modules/3.13.0-39-generic/build/include CC=/usr/bin/gcc GREP=/usr/bin/make IS_GCC_3=no VMCCVER=4.8
2014-11-10T10:59:37.173-08:00| vthread-3| I120: Failed to compile module vmblock!
2014-11-10T10:59:37.179-08:00| vthread-3| I120: Trying to find a suitable PBM set for kernel 3.13.0-39-generic.
2014-11-10T10:59:37.179-08:00| vthread-3| I120: Validating path /lib/modules/3.13.0-39-generic/build/include for kernel release 3.13.0-39-generic
2014-11-10T10:59:37.182-08:00| vthread-3| I120: Your GCC version: 4.8
2014-11-10T10:59:37.193-08:00| vthread-3| I120: Your GCC version: 4.8
2014-11-10T10:59:37.206-08:00| vthread-3| I120: Header path /lib/modules/3.13.0-39-generic/build/include for kernel release 3.13.0-39-generic is valid.
2014-11-10T10:59:37.206-08:00| vthread-3| I120: Building module vmci.
2014-11-10T10:59:37.206-08:00| vthread-3| I120: Extracting the sources of the vmci module.
2014-11-10T10:59:37.248-08:00| vthread-3| I120: Building module with command: /usr/bin/make -j -C /tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmci-only auto-build SUPPORT_SMP=1 HEADER_DIR=/lib/modules/3.13.0-39-generic/build/include CC=/usr/bin/gcc GREP=/usr/bin/make IS_GCC_3=no VMCCVER=4.8
2014-11-10T11:00:32.559-08:00| vthread-3| I120: Failed to compile module vmci!
2014-11-10T11:00:32.564-08:00| vthread-3| I120: Trying to find a suitable PBM set for kernel 3.13.0-39-generic.
2014-11-10T11:00:32.564-08:00| vthread-3| I120: Validating path /lib/modules/3.13.0-39-generic/build/include for kernel release 3.13.0-39-generic
2014-11-10T11:00:32.567-08:00| vthread-3| I120: Your GCC version: 4.8
2014-11-10T11:00:32.577-08:00| vthread-3| I120: Your GCC version: 4.8
2014-11-10T11:00:32.590-08:00| vthread-3| I120: Header path /lib/modules/3.13.0-39-generic/build/include for kernel release 3.13.0-39-generic is valid.
2014-11-10T11:00:32.590-08:00| vthread-3| I120: Building module vmci.
2014-11-10T11:00:32.590-08:00| vthread-3| I120: Extracting the sources of the vmci module.
2014-11-10T11:00:32.606-08:00| vthread-3| I120: Building module with command: /usr/bin/make -j -C /tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmci-only auto-build SUPPORT_SMP=1 HEADER_DIR=/lib/modules/3.13.0-39-generic/build/include CC=/usr/bin/gcc GREP=/usr/bin/make IS_GCC_3=no VMCCVER=4.8
2014-11-10T11:00:43.496-08:00| vthread-3| I120: Failed to compile module vmci!
```

Thanks for the help!!

Comment: Why wouldn't you use the latest version, 10?  Looks like version 8 is not compatible with the latest kernel.

Comment: A friend I know upgraded to 14.04 from 12.04 and it worked. I did a fresh install and it won't. The main reason would be the fact that I purchased the license.

Comment: Did you run the install script as root(sudo)?

Comment: Yes I did. Most solutions I have found only addres the issue with "Failed to compile module vmnet! But mine is failing on compiling all modules.

Comment: I added a solution, let me know if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Open Terminal

```
sudo apt-get install open-vm-tools open-vm-tools-dev open-vm-dkms open-vm-toolbox open-vm-tools-dev
```

This should do the trick, let me know though!